# Pygame: Adding an Escape key to exit whole game with stopwatch function

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game via Python on a Raspberry Pi. I'm using the GPIOs to light up an LED and detect a button switch.

I wanted to incorporate an ESC on the keyboard so we can exit at any time.

But whenever I add in the ESC key code into the main while loop. It doesn't work. The LED and Buttons work, but when I press on the ESC key, it doesn't do anything.
The loop runs to refresh/run a stopwatch and listen to an LED button via the GPIO.

I wanted some advice on how things like ESC key are handled in games. Especially with fast paced games where the loop and cycles are very fast.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Please see the code below:

```
# Importing all libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys, time, atexit, pygame

# Setup GPIO and Pygame
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pygame.init()

# Define Tuples and Variables
leds = (16,17,22,9,5)
switches = (19,4,27,10,11)
button_pressed = False
taskcomplete = False

# Pygame visual variables
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (1024,240) )
counterfont = pygame.font.Font('DSEG14Modern-Regular.ttf', 70)

# Set Pygame refresh rate variable = clock 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Clock variables
sec_val = 0
sec = 0
mins = 0
hours = 0

# Status variables
paused  = False
running = True

# Start the clock
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

# Defining Functions

# Function that renders segment display on screen 
def time_convert(sec):
    sec = sec % 60
    sec_val = ("Timer: {0}".format(round((sec), 2)))
    counting_text = counterfont.render(str(sec_val), 3, (134,145,255))
    counting_rect = counting_text.get_rect(left = screen.get_rect().left)
    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
    screen.blit(counting_text, (300,40))
    pygame.display.update()
    
# Stopwatch function to compute for a SS:MS based stopwatch
def stop_Watch():
    end_time = time.time()
    time_lapsed = end_time - start_time
    sec_val = time_convert(time_lapsed)

# Press Button 1 to start the game
def but_3():
    while GPIO.input(switches[2]) == GPIO.LOW:
        GPIO.output(leds[2],True)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        stop_Watch()
    GPIO.output(leds[2],False)
    print(" Button 3 is pressed! Exit")

start_time = time.time()

def buttonPress(channel):
    # This function gets called every time a button is pressed, if the button pressed is the same as the button
    # that is illuminated, then we set the "correct_button" variable to True,
    # otherwise we set the "incorrect_button" variable to True.
    # We need to set some variables to global so that this function can change their value.
    button_pressed = True

def exit():
    # This function gets called when we exit our script, using Ctrl+C
    print("GPIO Clean Up!")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    pygame.quit()


# This tells our script to use the "exit()" without this, our "exit()" function would never be called.
atexit.register(exit)

#Loop through the leds to set them up
for led in leds:
    # Set the led to be an ouput
    GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)
    # Turn the led off
    GPIO.output(led,False)

# Loop through the switches to set them up
for switch in switches:
    # Set the switch to be an input
    GPIO.setup(switch, GPIO.IN)
    # Add rising edge detection
    GPIO.add_event_detect(switch, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=300)
    # Add the function "buttonPress" to be called when switch is pressed.
    GPIO.add_event_callback(switch, buttonPress)


# Main sequence code
# Setup Pygame refresh rate to 120 fps
clock.tick(120)
# Start timer
start_time = time.time()

# Main loop
while running:
    # Press Button 1 to start the game
    while GPIO.input(switches[0]) == GPIO.LOW:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    print("escape pressed")
                    running = False

        GPIO.output(leds[0],True)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        stop_Watch()
    GPIO.output(leds[0],False)
    print(" Button 1 is pressed! Exit")
    running = False
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's in another while loop I'm guessing, so it's not in the `running` while loop anymore. You can add `pygame.quit()` to make it quit that way though:

```
# Main loop
while running:
    # Press Button 1 to start the game
    while GPIO.input(switches[0]) == GPIO.LOW:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    print("escape pressed")
                    pygame.quit()
                    running = False

        GPIO.output(leds[0],True)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        stop_Watch()
    GPIO.output(leds[0],False)
    print(" Button 1 is pressed! Exit")
    running = False
exit()
```

Or, since you have a function named `exit()` that does the same thing, you can add `exit()` to those places instead.